# Missing libraries out of netbeans in Platform Module application (netbeans 7.3.1)

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception, platform

I run the application inside Netbeans and it runs OK, bu I am getting a java.lang.NullPointerException when I run the application out of Netbeans. I create the .nbm to public them in the update server. When user apply the updates and run the application, they get the error. the log file is showed above.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.getMessage(Exceptions.java:238)
at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.toString(Exceptions.java:321)
at java.util.Objects.toString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Unknown Source)
at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate0(Exceptions.java:279)
at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate0(Exceptions.java:286)
at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate0(Exceptions.java:286)
at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate0(Exceptions.java:286)
at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate0(Exceptions.java:286)
at org.openide.util.Exceptions$AnnException.findOrCreate(Exceptions.java:256)
at org.openide.util.Exceptions.attachMessage(Exceptions.java:85)
at org.netbeans.modules.settings.convertors.XMLSettingsSupport$SettingsRecognizer.instanceCreate(XMLSettingsSupport.java:632)
at org.netbeans.modules.settings.convertors.SerialDataConvertor$SettingsInstance.instanceCreate(SerialDataConvertor.java:426)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.persistence.PersistenceManager.getTopComponentPersistentForID(PersistenceManager.java:571)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.persistence.PersistenceManager.getTopComponentForID(PersistenceManager.java:681)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.PersistenceHandler.getTopComponentForID(PersistenceHandler.java:489)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowManagerImpl.getTopComponentForID(WindowManagerImpl.java:957)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowManagerImpl.findTopComponent(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
at org.openide.windows.OpenComponentAction.getTopComponent(OpenComponentAction.java:76)
at org.openide.windows.OpenComponentAction.actionPerformed(OpenComponentAction.java:89)
at org.openide.awt.AlwaysEnabledAction$1.run(AlwaysEnabledAction.java:198)
at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker$1.run(ActionInvoker.java:95)
at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker.doPerformAction(ActionInvoker.java:116)
at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker.invokeAction(ActionInvoker.java:99)
at org.openide.awt.AlwaysEnabledAction.actionPerformed(AlwaysEnabledAction.java:201)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [catch] at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```